# Obfuscation of checksum guards

Tags: security, assembly, obfuscation, checksum

As part of my project, I have to insert small codes in a C program called checksum guards. What these guards do is they calculate the checksum value of a portion of code using a function(add, xor, etc.) which operates on the instruction opcodes. So, if somebody has tampered with the instructions(add, modify, delete) in that region of code, the checksum value will change and intrusion will be detected.

Here is the research paper which talks about this technique:

https://www.cerias.purdue.edu/assets/pdf/bibtex_archive/2001-49.pdf

Here is the guard template:

```
guard:
      add ebp, -checksum
      mov eax, client_addr

for:
      cmp eax, client_end
      jg end
      mov ebx, dword[eax]
      add ebp, ebx
      add eax, 4
      jmp for
end:
```

Now, I have two questions.

1. Would putting the guards in the assembly better than putting it in the source program?
2. Assuming I put them in the assembly(at an appropriate place) what kind of obfuscation should I use to prevent the guard template to be easily visible? (Since when I have more than 1 guard, the attacker should not easily find out all the guard templates and disable all the guards together as that would leave the code with no security)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From attacker's (without sources) point of view the first question doesn't matter; he's tampering with the final binary machine code, whether it was produced from .c or .s will make zero difference. So I would worry mainly how to generate the correct binary with appropriate checksums. I'm not aware of any way how to get proper checksum inside the C source. But I can imagine to have some external tool running over assembler files created by C compiler, in some post-process way - before compiling the .s files into .o. *But*... Keep in mind, that some calls and addresses are just relative offsets, and the binary loaded into memory is patched by the OS loader according to linker's table, to make those point to the real memory addresses. Thus the data bytes will change (opcodes will stay fixed).

Yours guard template doesn't take that into account, and does checksum whole opcodes with data bytes as well (Some advanced guards have opcodes definitions, and checksum/encrypt/decipher only the opcodes themselves without operand bytes).

Otherwise it's neat, that the result is damaged ebp value, ruining any C code around (*) working with stack variables. But it's still artificial test, you can simply comment out both add ebp,-checksum and add ebp,ebx making the guard harmless.

(*) notice you have to put the guard in between some classic C code to get some real runtime problems from invalid ebp value. If you would put it at the end of subroutine, which ends with pop ebp, everything would work well.

So to the second question:

You definitely want more malicious ways to guard correct value, than only ebp damage. Usually the hardest (to remove) way is to make checksum value part of some calculation, eventually skewing results just slightly, so serious usage of the SW will be impossible, but it will take time to notice by the user.

You can also use some genuine code loop to add your checksumming to it, so simply skipping whole loop will skip also valid code (but I can imagine this one only added by hand into generated assembly from C, so you will have to redo it after every new compilation of particular C source).

Then the particular guard template can be obfuscated by any imaginable mutation (different registers used, modified order of instructions, instruction variants), try to search about viruses with mutation encoding to get some ideas.

And I didn't read that paper, but from the Figures I would say the main point is to make those guarding areas to overlap, so patching off one of them will affect another one, which sounds to me like that extra sugar to make it somewhat functional (although this still looks like normal challenge to 8bit game crackers ;), not even "hard" level). But that also means you would need either very cunning external tool to calculate that cyclic tree of dependencies, and insert the guard templates in correct order, or do it again manually completely.

Of course when doing manually, you have to do it after each new C compilation, so it's worth of the effort only on something very precious and expensive, or rock solid stable, where you will not produce another revision for next 10y or so... :D

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I have a doubt .                                                     1. You said  "But... Keep in mind, that some calls and addresses are just relative offsets, and the binary loaded into memory is patched by the OS loader according to linker's table, to make those point to the real memory addresses. Thus the data bytes will change (opcodes will stay fixed)." How do I get around this?

Comment: Depends... From the assembly it looks like x86 platform. You can check this article to get some idea what is being relocated and how: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/08/25/load-time-relocation-of-shared-libraries  To get around this, you have to guard only internal code (no external symbol usage). But that's only part of it, internal code is still relocated because of address space randomization. You also want to use PIC ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code ). I'm not OS expert to guarantee these two suffice to prevent any binary load-time patching, but there's a chance.

Comment: Another way is to create guard code which does work only with instructions opcode, and not data bytes. So it will fetch only opcode byte, and then increase the memory pointer according to instruction length (the binary opcode can be parsed in some logical way to calculate instruction length on some CPUs, but x86 may be already so complex, that look up table may be of use here ... or mix both, especially if you know some particular guard will run only over some subset of opcodes, so your logic may fail for opcodes out of this range = additional guard test).

Comment: Okay. Thank you. Do you thing using encryption would be better(stronger to break) than simple obfuscation by changing the instructions and their order ? Also, since I want the obfuscation to be as strong as possible, do you know of any tool/technique by which strength of obfuscation can be evaluated?

Comment: But I sort of wonder why do you bother. SW released without source is [un]dead almost right at the point of release, so you are wasting your life time by creating something what will vanish soon.

Comment: Actually, it is not a software. I am working on a project in my college and as part of it I am integrating Return oriented programming with checksumming to strengthen the security. But I have no way of evaluating how strong it is.

Comment: Encryption is much better, because till you decrypt it, attacker can't read the instructions. OTOH if the attacker can use the SW in legitimate way, he has then also access to decrypted instructions too. In case you would use some external chip, cracking gets more difficult (expensive), see UEFI for example of current implementation. Maybe you can also read some stories about cracking Xbox and similar, to get idea how to make things complicated... yet still they get cracked eventually over time. If you have pure SW solution, and attacker can use the SW legitimately, it may resist days at most.

Comment: See, I just want to delay the process of reverse engineering the code. That is the aim as any attacker with time and resources will eventually be able to recover the code, right?

Comment: Sure, just question how expensive RE is. To evaluate that; I'm not expert, but I'm not aware of any universal scale/rules. There are professional services to evaluate security of your product (penetration testing + reviews). For **me** anything done purely in SW and depending only on user's device (no external server input needed for operation) is in principle "easy" to break = in real case may be anywhere from trivial (hours) to nightmare (year). But breakable. Adding HW crypto chip will narrow people able to break in (I'm out). But... (next comment)

Comment: Mind you, preventing RE and making product secure are two different things, often going against each other! Like "integrating Return oriented programming with checksumming to strengthen the security". That's bullshit. Your code guards will malfunction in case of tampering, thus increase the malicious effect of failure and making it easier to attack (from security standpoint). So you are increasing difficulty of RE, but also you will have harder time to ensure proper function of product, making it more fragile. Only security-by-obscurity is strengthened by your approach = not real security.